# Running into a NullReferenceException in my C# code, and I can't figure out why!!!! Unity3D Button Issue :(

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I'm running into issues with my room button in Unity. When pressed(compiled or in editor), I get this error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object RoomButton.OpenRoom () (at Assets/Scripts/RoomButton.cs:21)

line 21 is this line:  Launcher.instance.JoinRoom(info);

I'll paste both my Launcher code and my RoomButton code below. Please tell me where I made the mistake :(

If it's not in the code, let me know and I can triple check the Unity button settings, but they look perfect tbh.

RoomButton Code:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using TMPro;
    using Photon.Realtime;

    public class RoomButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public TMP_Text buttonText;
    private RoomInfo info;

    public void SetButtonDetails(RoomInfo inputInfo)
    {
        info = inputInfo;

        buttonText.text = info.Name;
    }

    public void OpenRoom()
    {
        Launcher.instance.JoinRoom(info);
    }
}
```

Launcher Code here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Realtime;
public class Launcher : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{

    public static Launcher instance;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void wake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public GameObject loadingScreen;
    public TMP_Text loadingText;

    public GameObject menuButtons;

    public GameObject createRoomScreen;
    public TMP_InputField roomNameInput;
    public GameObject roomScreen;
    public TMP_Text roomNameText, playerNameLabel;
    private List<TMP_Text> allPlayerNames = new List<TMP_Text>();
    public GameObject errorScreen;
    public TMP_Text errorText;
    public GameObject roomBrowserScreen;
    public RoomButton theRoomButton;
    private List<RoomButton> allRoomButtons = new List<RoomButton>();

    public GameObject nameInputScreen;
    public TMP_InputField nameInput;
    private bool hasSetNick;

    public string levelToPlay;
    public GameObject startButton;

    void Start()
    {
        CloseMenus();

        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        loadingText.text = "Connecting To Network...";

        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();


    }

    void CloseMenus()
    {
        loadingScreen.SetActive(false);
        menuButtons.SetActive(false);
        createRoomScreen.SetActive(false);
        roomScreen.SetActive(false);
        errorScreen.SetActive(false);
        roomBrowserScreen.SetActive(false);
        nameInputScreen.SetActive(false);
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();

        loadingText.text = "Joining Lobby...";

        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        menuButtons.SetActive(true);

        PhotonNetwork.NickName = Random.Range(0, 1000).ToString();

        if(!hasSetNick)
        {
            CloseMenus();
            nameInputScreen.SetActive(true);

            if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("playerName"))
            {
                nameInput.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("playerName");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PhotonNetwork.NickName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("playerName");
        }
    }
    public void OpenRoomCreate()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        createRoomScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roomNameInput.text))
        {
            RoomOptions options = new RoomOptions();
            options.MaxPlayers = 8;

            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomNameInput.text, options);

            CloseMenus();
            loadingText.text = "Creating Room...";
            loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        roomScreen.SetActive(true);
        roomNameText.text = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name;

        ListAllPlayers();

        if(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            startButton.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            startButton.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void ListAllPlayers()
    {
        foreach(TMP_Text player in allPlayerNames)
        {
            Destroy(player.gameObject);
        }
        allPlayerNames.Clear();

        Player[] players = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;
        for(int i = 0; i <players.Length; i++)
        {
            TMP_Text newPlayerLabel = Instantiate(playerNameLabel, playerNameLabel.transform.parent);
            newPlayerLabel.text = players[i].NickName;
            newPlayerLabel.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            allPlayerNames.Add(newPlayerLabel);
        }
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
            TMP_Text newPlayerLabel = Instantiate(playerNameLabel, playerNameLabel.transform.parent);
            newPlayerLabel.text = newPlayer.NickName;
            newPlayerLabel.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            allPlayerNames.Add(newPlayerLabel);
    }

    public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
    {
        ListAllPlayers();
    }

    public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        errorText.text = "Failed To Create Room: " + message;
        CloseMenus();
        errorScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void CloseErrorScreen()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        menuButtons.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void LeaveRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        CloseMenus();
        loadingText.text = "Leaving Room";
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public override void OnLeftRoom()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        menuButtons.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void OpenRoomBrowser()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        roomBrowserScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void CloseRoomBrowser()
    {
        CloseMenus();
        menuButtons.SetActive(true);
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach(RoomButton rb in allRoomButtons)
        {
            Destroy(rb.gameObject);
        }
        allRoomButtons.Clear();

        theRoomButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        for(int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
        {
            if(roomList[i].PlayerCount != roomList[i].MaxPlayers && !roomList[i].RemovedFromList)
            {
                RoomButton newButton = Instantiate(theRoomButton, theRoomButton.transform.parent);
                newButton.SetButtonDetails(roomList[i]);
                newButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                allRoomButtons.Add(newButton);
           }
        }
    }

    public void JoinRoom(RoomInfo inputInfo)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(inputInfo.Name);

        CloseMenus();
        loadingText.text = "Joining Room";
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void SetNickName()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameInput.text))
        {
            PhotonNetwork.NickName = nameInput.text;

            PlayerPrefs.SetString("playerName", nameInput.text);

            CloseMenus();
            menuButtons.SetActive(true);

            hasSetNick = true;
        }
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(levelToPlay);
    }

    public override void OnMasterClientSwitched(Player newMasterClient)
    {
        if(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            startButton.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            startButton.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void QuickJoin()
    {
        RoomOptions options = new RoomOptions();
        options.MaxPlayers = 8;

        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("Test");
        CloseMenus();
        loadingText.text = "Creating Test Room";
        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? Seems like `.instance` is null

Comment: I do not, at least not yet. And earlier in the code I have instance = this; is that not correct? Thank you for the time \o/

Comment: You have `instance = this;` in a private `wake()` method that appears never to be called in the code you've shown. Did you mean to call that from `Start()`? (Also note that you've posted over 300 lines of code - it would really help both you and us if you could try to reduce this to a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: yeah, you found it lol. That needed to be Awake, not wake xD i was staring at every bit of code EXCEPT that part way up top. Thank you so much for your time \o/

Comment: I genuinely suggest you put some time into learning how the debugger works and how to use it